# Exif javascript not returning GPS information while take picture in camera Mobile

Tags: javascript, .net, mobile, photo, exif

We are having the .NET core web app using both dropzone and EXIF to upload picture and find GPS lattitude and longtitude details from the photo.

We created an android app using the same code as webview , here the problem is, though the camera settings allowed to share location , exif not returning GPS details. But same working if the picture is already taken and upload via gallery app.

Code in javascript

```
new Dropzone("#dropzone", {
                url: "#",
                paramName: "file", //the parameter name containing the uploaded file
                clickable: true,
                uploadMultiple: true,
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                autoProcessQueue: true,
                //acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.PNG,.JPG",
                acceptedFiles: "image/*",
                capture: "camera",
                dictDefaultMessage: "<strong>Drop files here or click to upload. </strong>", //override the default text
                init: function () {
                    this.on('addedfile', function (file) {
                        if ($("#dropzone").hasClass('dropzone')) {
                            jQuery("#dropzone").attr('style', 'background-image: none !important;');
                        }

                        var isExist = existingImageName.filter(function (item) { return item === file.name });
                        if (isExist.length > 0) {
                            abp.notify.error("Image with this name is already exist,please select image with different name");
                            this.removeFile(file);
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            existingImageName.push(file.name);
                            imagefile.push(file);
                            var objFile = this;
                            console.log("exif calls");
                            dealLocationLat = "";
                            dealLocationLng = "";
                            EXIF.getData(file, function () {
                                    if (Object.keys(this.exifdata).length > 0) {
                                        if (AgeofImage(this.exifdata) || DealImageDateCheck(this.exifdata.DateTime)) {
                                            var allMetaData = EXIF.getAllTags(this);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNElE.png)

I tried in web browsers and it is working fine and in mobile browser chrome both camera and gallery app working well and good. App also working well with gallery app sharing photo but taking camera picture from app not returning GPS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed "addedfile" event to complete, then it returns the geo-locations.

it was like below

`````
then I moved my code like below.

````this.on('complete', function (file) { //code here });
`````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).